# Using a for loop to reverse an array does nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I am trying to reverse an array of 15 numbers by using a for loop, but for some reason the array order stays the same.

My code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[15] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[15 - i - 1];
        arr[15 - i - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    j = 0;
    do {
        std::cout << arr[j] << " ";
        j++;
    } while (j < 15);
}
```

Any idea what have I done wrong?

Comment: Ask yourself, If you swap 2 elements per iterations, how many iterations do you need to have `number_of_swaps == number_of_elements` (Or more philosophically: how far can you walk into a forest)

Comment: You're reversing it twice.

Comment: Next time, please paste up a snippet of code which compiles; i.e. put `int main()` around what you've written. Better still, edit the question.

Comment: I start to think this should be a c++-faq.

Comment: The good news is, now that you understand the algorithm, you never have to do this again. There's a reason [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) comes with the standard library.

Comment: Why don't you simply iterate from `std::rbegin(arr)` to `std::rend(arr)` to get your reversed view? Or construct a `std::array<std:: reference_wrapper<int>> reverse_arr_view(std::rbegin(arr), std::rend(arr));` ? Or use `std::reverse`. Or similar - no need for all that swap business - it's a oneliner.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you swap all the elements back again once `i` is past the half-way point.

To reverse, you only need to go half way; i.e. run `i` to 15 / 2.